# Import vendor proto on own proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

How to import external (on vendor folder) proto into my own proto?

I'm using this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package command;
option go_package = "api";

import "github.com/service/command.proto";

service CommandService {
    rpc Push(Command) returns (PushResponse);
}

message PushResponse {
    string id = 1;
}
```

But I get an error that the file was not found:

```
> protoc -I api api/command.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:api
github.com/service/command.proto: File not found.
```

Also this gives the same error:

```
> protoc -I api -I vendor/github.com/service api/command.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:api
github.com/service/command.proto: File not found.
```

I tried prefixing with `vendor/` on .proto file as well with no success.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing-definitions): "The protocol compiler searches for imported files in a set of directories specified on the protocol compiler command line using the -I/--proto_path flag. [...] In general you should set the --proto_path flag to the root of your project and use fully qualified names for all imports." -I expects directory names as arguments; -I github.com/service/command.proto makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with vendor as well with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `-I` per **folder** from which to *start* looking for imports. `import` then tries all of them using the relative paths specified in the import statement; so: to use:

```
protoc -I api [other-options] some.proto
```

where `some.proto` has `import "github.com/service/command.proto";`, then you would need a file-system layout like:

```
[current folder]
- some.proto
- [api]
  - [github.com]
    - [service]
      - command.proto
```

(where `[...]` is a folder)

Note that if you omit `-I`, then the current directory is assumed as a single import root, so you could have:

```
[current folder]
- some.proto
- [github.com]
  - [service]
    - command.proto
```

and just use `protoc [other-options] some.proto`

Comment: @CaeVecchi you need to generate the code for the import separately; the actual "import" just tells it what to expect. You can either specify multiple input files on a single `protoc` call, or you can make multiple `protoc` calls

Comment: Yeah, started to realise that. Thanks @Marc-Gravell

Comment: So, this is how I did: from api folder:
```protoc -I ../vendor command.proto -I . --go_out=plugins=grpc:.```
proto file ended up with this on import:
```import "github.com/service/command.proto";```
Thanks again @Marc-Gravell